# Powerpoint-like web page creator

Tags: windows, gratis, web-development, html-editor, powerpoint

Tl;dr Gratis, Windows, PowerPoint-like  HTML5 static webpage creator

I am developing a browser-based app for someone. I am not exactly graphically gifted, nor am I a CSS guru, so that pretty page layout does not come easily to me.

He is totally untechnical, but does do very good PowerPoint, which he emails to me as screen mock-ups.

I searched all over for a PowerPoint to HTML converter, but failed. I tried the [official Microsoft suggestion](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/980553/the-options-to-save-a-presentation-as-a-webpage-are-not-available-in-the-save-as-dialog-box-in-powerpoint-2010). However, when I look at the generated HTML, it seems like the page content is just a bitmap embedded in the HTML.

So, it looks like I will have to get him to use a web page creation program.

The idea is that the can drag & drop boxes (with rounded corner option), text, boxes containing text, etc, then resize/colo()u)r them, etc

The gratis Windows program which achieves this should be as close to PowerPoint as possible, with no tricky new concepts.

It should be able to export to HTML. I have a strong preference for HTML, and a strong preference for separation of contents and presentation into HTML and CSS, although I can live with them mixed in one file, if the app is very PowerPoint-like.

I will then take his static web page and covert it to dynamic HTML using AngularJs, creating edit boxes, list boxes, combo boxes, check boxes & radio buttons if necessary, and adding code to handle them.

Comment: "close to PowerPoint as possible" - is Impress from  [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) suite

Comment: WOw! How did I overlook that? Feel free to dress it up a little & post it as an answer. Hint: you might want to refer to https://help.libreoffice.org/Impress/Saving_a_Presentation_in_HTML_Format

Comment: Belay that comment! Alas, it is no better than PowerPoint; it's exports are mostly just images.

Comment: If you select File->Export you will get export window where in "Save as type" you can choose html/xhtml/pdf/swf and images. HTML option is above `-------` line in selection menu

Comment: Yes, I found it, but what is generated is not really usable to create my own HTML from it :-(

Comment: Agree, all auto-generated solutions aren't perfect and need additional parsing to clean it up. There is also pretty old project [Kompozer](http://kompozer.net/) - WYSIWYG web page editing, but as I said, all such WYSIWYG solutions generating awful source HTML code

Comment: I have used Konpozer for many, many, years. Alas, I fear that it is beyond my friend ;-( I really need something very, very simple - which generates good CSS.